# Webpage filename conventions

Tags: security, html, conventions, administration

I'm just looking through a web project, and they've used a web page file naming convention based on the project plan docs.

It got me wondering: Are there security considerations of webpage filenames?  Or any other external considerations that might affect a webpage filename convention?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web page conventions helps to makes the webpage compatible with multi-platforms. 
In Unix uppercase names case sensitive but in windows platforms the names aren't case sensitive.
Some very old platforms can have only max 8 letters in file names and extensions can have only three letters.
So its safer to use 8.3 convention lowercase. 
max 8 letters webpage name and 3 letter for extension(*.htm,*.asp, etc..,)